# Agendador de tarefas no Heroku para executar script PHP

Tags: php, symfony-2, heroku

Preciso executar um script PHP no Heroku com o agendador de tarefas, estou lendo este [artigo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) mais não estou compreendendo. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2):

Eu não tenho certeza do que você quer dizer com "executar meus próprios tarefas agendadas manualmente." Para cron especificamente, você precisa de acesso a crontab, que eles podem controlar, como eles são seus servidores. Se você tem uma outra maneira de fazê-lo, ele provavelmente seria bom, mas ter em mente que o seu aplicativo não está vinculado a um servidor específico quando executados no Heroku, e que o servidor irá mudar entre as execuções.

Além disso, a menos que tenha mudado desde a última vez que eu chequei, você pode executar tarefas diárias cron de graça, mas a cada hora custa R $ 3 / mo.

E claro uma noticia boa as crons são gratuitas utilizando este addon:

http://addons.heroku.com/scheduler

Comment: Eu não falei isso : "executar meus próprios tarefas agendadas manualmente.". Mas obrigado pela dica já deu tudo certo, mais tarde posto um tutorial mostrando como fazer.

Comment: perfeito espero ter ajudado